# Java Swing packs the window wrong

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a Scorched Earth like game in Java (for my exam project :D), but I have this problem. I'm drawing a window (JFrame), setting layout to BorderLayout, applying an extended JPanel, and packing the window, but after it has been packed, it's showing some extended white space at the left and bottom border.

This is my main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("game title");
        panel p = new panel(new java.awt.Dimension(512, 512));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(p, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

panel is my JPanel class, which in the constructor is setting it's preferred size to the argument (512x512). I've tested this on both Windows and Linux, and the error it at both places, and the size of the white gap differs from OS to OS.

This is my panel class:

```
class panel extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    panel(java.awt.Dimension size){
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }
    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g){
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You didn't tell us about your panel class. What does it do? What does the constructor argument do? Can you reduce the problem to a SSCCE? http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I don't see your problem with the provided Panel class. Also you repeat yourself by hard-coding the preferred size of the panel in two places. Don't do that!

Comment: I have a size variable with the size of the window which I'm using to set the size of the rect, just removed it here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing:

```
setResizable(false);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by removing setResizable method also. But is there another way to prevent windows from being resized?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to reproduce this without your `panel` class (which needs a better name and should at least be named using CamelCase):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("game title");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(512, 512));
        p.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(p, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This produces a window with a blue 512x512 panel in it and no differently-colored border. So the problem must be with your `panel` class.

Comment: What is 522x522? The Window? Or the panel? My panel is exactly 512x512, while the Window is obviously a bit bigger than that.

Comment: It's the panel that's 522x522

Answer (score 3):

saua,

This isn't what you asked, but it's important never the less... You don't override *paint* in swing; instead you override *paintComponent*.

See Sun's "Custom Painting" tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

In fact, I strongly suggest (considering your choice of project) that you go through the whole Swing tutorial. It takes "a while", but it's worth the time.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the code of `setResizable()` and figured out that everything's right. Just put `this.setResizable(false)` *before* `this.pack()`.